# How safe is ref when used with unsafe code?

Tags: c#, unsafe

Using Microsoft Visual C# 2010, I recently noticed that you can pass objects by ref to unmanaged code. So I tasked myself with attempting to write some unmanaged code that converts a C++ char* to a a C# string using a callback to managed code. I made two attempts.

**Attempt 1:** Call unmanaged function that stores a ref parameter. Then, once that function has returned to managed code, call a another unmanaged function that calls a callback function that converts the char* to a managed string.

```
C++
typedef void (_stdcall* CallbackFunc)(void* ManagedString, char* UnmanagedString);

CallbackFunc UnmanagedToManaged = 0;
void* ManagedString = 0;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall StoreCallback(CallbackFunc X) {
    UnmanagedToManaged = X;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall StoreManagedStringRef(void* X) {
    ManagedString = X;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall CallCallback() {
    UnmanagedToManaged(ManagedString, "This is an unmanaged string produced by unmanaged code");
}

C#
[DllImport("Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void StoreCallback(CallbackFunc X);
[DllImport("Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void StoreManagedStringRef(ref string X);
[DllImport("Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void CallCallback();

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void CallbackFunc(ref string Managed, IntPtr Native);

static void Main(string[] args) {
    string a = "This string should be replaced";

    StoreCallback(UnmanagedToManaged);
    StoreManagedStringRef(ref a);
    CallCallback();
}

static void UnmanagedToManaged(ref string Managed, IntPtr Unmanaged) {
    Managed = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Unmanaged);
}
```

**Attempt 2:** Pass string ref to unmanaged function that passes the string ref to the managed callback.

```
C++
typedef void (_stdcall* CallbackFunc)(void* ManagedString, char* UnmanagedString);

CallbackFunc UnmanagedToManaged = 0;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall StoreCallback(CallbackFunc X) {
    UnmanagedToManaged = X;
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DoEverything(void* X) {
    UnmanagedToManaged(X, "This is an unmanaged string produced by unmanaged code");
}

C#
[DllImport("Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void StoreCallback(CallbackFunc X);
[DllImport("Name.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void DoEverything(ref string X);

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public delegate void CallbackFunc(ref string Managed, IntPtr Unmanaged);

static void Main(string[] args) {
    string a = "This string should be replaced";

    StoreCallback(UnmanagedToManaged);
    DoEverything(ref a);
}

static void UnmanagedToManaged(ref string Managed, IntPtr Unmanaged) {
    Managed = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Unmanaged);
}
```

Attempt 1 doesn't work but attempt 2 does. In attempt 1 it seems that as soon as the unmanaged code returns after storing the ref, the ref becomes invalid. Why is this happening?

Given the outcomes of attempt 1, I have doubts that attempt 2 will work reliably. So, how safe is ref on the unmanaged side of code when used with unmanaged code? Or in other words, what won't work in unmanaged code when using ref?

Things I'd like to know are are:

What exactly happens when objects are passed using ref to unmanaged code?

Does it guarantee that the objects will stay at their current position in memory while the ref is being used in unmanaged code?

What are the limitations of ref (what can't I do with a ref) in unmanaged code?

Comment: Unsafe code is called "unsafe" for a reason... it's unsafe. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete discussion of how p/invoke works is beyond the proper scope of a Stack Overflow Q&A. But briefly:

In neither of your examples are you really passing the address of your managed variable to the unmanaged code. The p/invoke layer includes marshaling logic that translates your managed data to something usable by the unmanaged code, and then translates back when the unmanaged code returns.

In both examples, the p/invoke layer has to create an intermediate object for the purpose of marshaling. In the first example, this object is gone by the time you call the unmanaged code again. Of course in the second example, it's not, since all of the work happens all at once.

I believe that your second example should be safe to use. That is, the p/invoke layer is smart enough to handle `ref` correctly in that case. The first example is unreliable because p/invoke is being misused, not because of any fundamental limitation of `ref` parameters.

A couple of additional points:

- I wouldn't use the word "unsafe" here. Yes, calling out to unmanaged code is in some ways unsafe, but in C# "unsafe" has a very specific meaning, related to the use of the `unsafe` keyword. I don't see anything in your code example that actually uses `unsafe`.
- In both examples, you have a bug related to your use of the delegate passed to unmanaged code. In particular, while the p/invoke layer can translate your managed delegate reference to a function pointer that unmanaged code can use, it doesn't know anything about the *lifetime* of the delegate object. It will keep the object alive long enough for the p/invoked method call to complete, but if you need it to live longer than that (as would be the case here), you need to do that yourself. For example, use `GC.KeepAlive()` on a variable in which you've stored the reference. (You likely can reproduce a crash by inserting a call to `GC.Collect()` between the call to `StoreCallback()` and the later call to unmanaged code where the function pointer would be used).

Comment: You're right about the second additional point. Inserting the GC.Collect() caused a crash. I would assume that keeping a static reference of the delegate would also work.